# How to implement LogisticRegressionCv on flutter

Tags: python, flutter, classification

i have LogisticRegressionCv model it's `.pkl` file and import data as images but i don't know how to get it on flutter please help me If you know how or if I must to convert my model to other file formats.

please help me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here is an [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-make-a-cross-platform-image-classifying-app-with-flutter-and-fastai-2a6af6701535) that might help you

Comment: @AtharvaGundawar I have tried his model is cnn but my model is logistic regression When I try to deploy on render it throws an error.

Comment: Whats your error ?

Comment: @AtharvaGundawar it's  `RuntimeError: Invalid magic number; corrupt file?`

Comment: PyTorch uses a magic number to identify the file format or protocol, Could you try to use `torch.save` instead of `pickle.dump`?

Answer (score 0):

as you've trained your model in python and stored it in pkl file. One method is in your flutter background, call `python3 predict_yourmodel.py your_model_params` and after the run, it will give your the model result.
Another way is implement a logisticRegressionCv in Flutter as it is a simple model, and easily be implemented. you can store all your params and l1 or l2 etc super-params in a `txt` instead of pkl file for readility.

Comment: How do I save the model as a txt file, do you have a way?

Comment: you can print attributes of your logres_cv, such as `print(lr_cv.coef_)`, and Cs_ if you have used regularization in your model. have a reference on [sklearn-lr_cv](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV)